# LWJGL png texture transparency (textureColour.a white color instead of black)

Tags: java, opengl, transparency, lwjgl, alpha

I have grass models textured by PNG pictures. And i get white background color instead of black, which I want to. Why it is so and what should i do to fix that? I am using **LWJGL 3** and **PNGDecoder.jar**

[image]

Texture loader code:

```
public int loadTexture(String fileName) {
    ByteBuffer buf = null;
    int tWidth = 0;
    int tHeight = 0;

    try {
        // Open the PNG file as an InputStream
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("res/" + fileName + ".png");
        // Link the PNG decoder to this stream
        PNGDecoder decoder = new PNGDecoder(in);

        // Get the width and height of the texture
        tWidth = decoder.getWidth();
        tHeight = decoder.getHeight();

        // Decode the PNG file in a ByteBuffer
        buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                4 * decoder.getWidth() * decoder.getHeight());
        decoder.decode(buf, decoder.getWidth() * 4, Format.RGBA);
        buf.flip();

        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    // Create a new texture object in memory and bind it
    int textureId = GL11.glGenTextures();
    GL13.glActiveTexture(textureId);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    // All RGB bytes are aligned to each other and each component is 1 byte
    GL11.glPixelStorei(GL11.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    // Upload the texture data and generate mip maps (for scaling)
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, tWidth, tHeight, 0,
            GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
    GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Setup the ST coordinate system
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);

    // Setup what to do when the texture has to be scaled
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GL11.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    return textureId;
}
```

Comment: Could we see your shaders, and could we have a download to the image? Remember that ThinMatrix's image that you download from the website actually isn't transparent. Also, have you tried checking if the R G and B values are 100% white and making it transparent that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want transparent textures to look transparent, you have to enable blending first. Put the following somewhere in your OpenGL initialization code.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

---

You are also internally storing your texture in RGB instead of RGBA format.

```
GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, tWidth, tHeight, 0,
    GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
```

should become

```
GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA8, tWidth, tHeight, 0,
    GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
```

Comment: It's not working.. I want to set it on shader by st. like:
vec4 textureColour = texture(modelTexture, pass_textureCoords);
    if (textureColour.a < 0.5) {
        discard;
    }

But I rly dont know why is the background white and not black.

Comment: Why do you want the grass to have a black background? Or do you mean a transparent one so you can see the other objects through it?

Comment: I am following tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyzXBYVvjsg&index=15&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP ). He is using lwjgl2, I lwjgl3. So I have some differences in code. And here is problem, because he have background black and I white. Rly dont know why. I think it could be caused by my loadTexture method, which I wrote by myself. At 2:05 you can see what I want.

Comment: It could be because you are storing your texture data in the wrong format - see the edit.

Comment: I don't mean the file on your hard drive, but the texture stored by OpenGL. Look at the code statements above: You are passing `GL_RGB` as the internal format, which means the texture won't have any transparency information.

Comment: I saw, unfortunately no difference.

Comment: Image was rly corrupted. Thnx for time.